# Proof containing pairwise disjoint sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I came across the following question while studying.
Let $A,B,C,D$ be pairwise disjoint sets. Prove that if $|A| = |B|$ and $|C| = |D|$ then $|A \cup C| = |B \cup D|$.

I thought of the fact that they intersections are obviously empty but this doesn't help with the progression to a solution. I also tried to find any properties of the pairwise disjoint union that might help but I am stuck. Can anyone offer some suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Are you sure that you have written the complete question ?
Consider $A=\{a,b,c\}$, $B=\{d,e,f\}$, $C\{1,2,3\}$ and $D=\{1,2,3\}$. Then it contradicts your conclusion.

Comment: If $A,B = \emptyset$, $C = \{1\}$, $D = \{2\}$, then $|A| = |B| = 0$, $|C| = |D| = 1$, and $A,B,C,D$ are pairwise disjoint (as mentioned in your title), but $|A \cup B| = 0 \neq 2 = |C \cup D|$. Are you sure the problem statement is correct?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You know that $$|A \cup C| = |A|+|C|-|A \cap C|.$$
Similarly, $$|B \cup D| = |B|+|D|-|B \cap D|.$$
Also, since $A,B,C,D$ are pairwise disjoint, the intersection of any two of them is the empty set. Hence, $$|A \cap C| = |B \cap D| = 0.$$

Now, do you see how to prove that $|A \cup C| = |B \cup D|$?

Comment: Just in case the sets are not necessarily finite:

Because of the cardinality assumptions, there are one-to-one and onto functions $f:A\to B$ and $g:C\to D$. Define $h:A\cup C\to B\cup D$ by letting $h(x)$ be $f(x)$ or $g(x)$, depending on whether $x$ is in $A$ or $C$. Using the pairwise disjointness where necessary, show that $h$ is well-defined, one-to-one, and onto.

Comment: I still don't exactly see how to proceed. Is it similar to the property of equality stating that a + b = b + c implies a = b?

Comment: SteveKass: Good point, the sets might not be finite. 
dreamin: Look at the right sides of first two equations. You are given that $|A| = |B|$ and that $|C| = |D|$. We also know that $|A \cap C| = |B \cap D| = 0$. Do you see how $|A|+|C|-|A \cap C| = |B|+|D|-|B \cap D|$?

Comment: @SteveKass I would then I have to come up with a bijective function from |$A \cup B$| to |$C \cup D$|?

Comment: The function $h$ I described is a bijection from $A\cup B$ to $C\cup D$ (what you asked, but without the absolute value signs). If you can show that $h$ is in fact a bijection, that will prove that the sets in question have equal cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my
inductive of cardinality
for finite sets:

$|\emptyset| = 0
$.

If
$x \in A$
then
$|A \cup \{x\}|
=|A|
$.
If
$x \not\in A$
then
$|A \cup \{x\}|
=|A|+1
$.

Theorem:
If $A$ and $B$
are pairwise disjoint,
then
$|A \cup B|
=|A| + |B|
$.

Proof by induction
on $|B|$.

If
$|B| = 0$,
then
$A \cup B
= A
$,
so the base case is proven.

Suppose it is true
for $|B| \le n$.
If $|B| =n+1$
and
$|A \cap B|
=\emptyset
$,
then
$B = B' \cup \{x\}$
where
$x \not\in B'$
and
$x \not\in A$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
|A \cup B|
&=|A \cup (B' \cup \{x\})|\\
&=|(A \cup \{x\}) \cup B'|\\
&=|(A \cup \{x\})|+ |B'|\\
&=|A|+1+ |B'|\\
&=|A|+(|B'|+1)\\
&=|A|+|B|\\
\end{array}
$